Sharepoint online: how to use a custom content type in Page Site library?
I'm trying to create and use a custom content type for page sites in Sharepoint Online.
My use case is that I want to build a page which will display several news carousel and I want to separate the news based on their type so I thought using a content type would be ideal for this.
I was able to create a custom content type (following this https://joannecklein.com/2018/07/14/modern-page-content-types/), and it's showing in the existing "Site Pages" library as an available content type, I can add columns etc.. I'm happy so far.
However I'm stuck when trying to make use of it. I cannot find how to create a page of my custom content type, it's defaulting to the base page and I cannot figure out how to change that.
When I'm on the Site Pages library, the new button is only offerring me to create new "Link" and I can't create new pages from there.
I also cannot create another page library as suggested here How to assign Custom content type to sharepoint page? maybe
(maybe I don't have the access or it's been turned off I don't know, I'm not the admin).
I feel like I'm missing something obvious but can't figure out what
Many thanks

Please check whether you have successfully added the new content type to the Page Library:
Go to Library Settings, in Content Types section, see if there is a content type you created. If not, click Add from existing site content types to add it.

After the addition is successful, click New in the page library to check whether you can see the added content type.


Hi thanks for the response, I have a custom content type that shows Visible on New Button but it's still not showing, the only option available on New when I'm at the library level is "Link". I'm in the OOTB Site Pages library, I haven't tried creating a different library, although I'm unsure if that'd help
